# Wait until all objects are loaded to put on map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to plot several hundred building footprints on google maps. But I'm having an issue with callbacks (I think)...

To do this, after the Google Map is loaded, I get a list of building IDs from the database and for each ID, I create a new Building object.

### Main Page

```
function load_buildings() {
    var url='/api/get_imaged_buildings/';
    $.getJSON(url, function(buildings) {
        for(var building in buildings) {
            var new_building = new Building(buildings[building].id, buildings[building].footprint);
        }
    })
    .error(function(jqXhr, textStatus, error) {
        alert("ERROR: " + textStatus + ", " + error);
    });
}
```

That returns:

```
{"507ca17f0f53664a62000fc0": {"footprint": [[-71.06344334281945, 42.354043084935846], [-71.0637134471212, 42.35412603649889], [-71.06333405397038, 42.35480611690739], [-71.06338439864643, 42.35482782501911], [-71.0632517948924, 42.355064458152995], [-71.063047338961, 42.35496617995809], [-71.06308636758757, 42.35492158377903], [-71.06293828848663, 42.35485043826673], [-71.06289913717758, 42.354895213988364], [-71.06272577376158, 42.35481190819347], [-71.06319845721484, 42.35438624633442], [-71.06344334281945, 42.354043084935846]], "id": "507ca17f0f53664a62000fc0"},
```

### Building.js

```
function Building(id, footprint) {
    this.id = id;
    this.footprint = footprint;
}
Building.prototype.plotFootprint = function() {
    var footprint = [];
    var footprint_from_db = this.footprint;
    for(var i=0; i<footprint_from_db.length; i++)
    {
        var location = footprint_from_db[i];
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]);
        bounds.extend(point);
        footprint.push(point);
    }
    var building = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: footprint,
        strokeColor: '#e81971',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });
    building.setMap(map);
}
```

What I want to do is plot all the buildings after they all have loaded. What is the best way to do this? I'd like to optimize for speed.

Thanks.

Edit: I took out the bad code and went with what works. Now I'm wondering how to determine when all footprints are loaded in all objects and then where should I plot them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a thing called a Deffered object -- it lets you set up a series of callbacks to run in sequence, and then run a bit of code once everything is wrapped up.

Check out the dox: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: How do I add a callback on creating an object?